# How can I program Excel to Work with Outlook?

Tags: excel, api, outlook

I have a fairly large Excel file.  In this file there is a column with dates.  I would like to know if/how it would be possible to make a program that would be able to read the date and post a notice 30 days in advance to Outlook Calendar or send out an email through Outlook in my office.  Is there a decent API that I could use for this?  If so, where may I find one?  Or, are there any existing programs capable of this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to write an Excel VBA script that interacts with Outlook.
See http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/olAutomating.htm for a good guide on this.
Specifically http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/olCalendar.htm#Creating_an_Appointment mentions how to create Calendar items. Just be aware most samples are for Outlook/Excel 2000, i imagine most should still work with newer versions but some objects may be renamed.

[Outlook Code](http://outlookcode.com/) is another good site with code samples for Outlook integration in general. Eg. http://outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=49

Of course you don't have to code everything inside Excel you should easily be able to do the same thing in a custom application (eg. a .NET application).

Answer (score 2):

You can run a macro when opening to excel sheet to check and update the calender and send email.

Here is an [example](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3564) about how to send email via outlook frommexcel. But the problem is that outlook will show us a security popup saying Excel is trying to send an email using outlook and whether you want to allow it or not.

Here is another [example](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning) which shows how to override this security warning.

This thred has an [example](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/how-send-email-using-vb-using-smtp_t5431.html) about how to send email using an mail server if you are interested (havne't tried it).

And here is an [example](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=1436) about how to add an event to outlook calander. Hope this helps.